# How to perform in and not in operation just like in SQL without using SQL query or SQL / table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

This is the SQL query

```
select * 
from Students
where StudentID in (select StudentID from FeeEntry);
```

I want to perform this SQL query in ASP.NET Core MVC without using SQL query command or any other procedure or with `SqlDataAdapter`.

I want this format.

The format of C# code:

```
var myvalues = (from values in  _context.students
                where values.studentID in table2   // where studentID is the foreign key 
                select values).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Entity Framework, you can find information here:

1. Read about Entity Framework [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/?redirectedfrom=MSDN).
2. Read about LINQ to SQL [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/bb308959(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Then your code would look like this:

```
var ids = _context.FeeEntry.Select(x => x.StudentID).tolist();
var myvalues =  _context.students.where(x => ids.Contains(x.studentID)).toList();
```